# how to make awesomium drag host window?

Tags: javascript, c#, wpf, awesomium

Im trying to make a widget like application, with awesomium and wpf, the webpage have buttons to minimize, close and drag the host window, minimize and close didnt give me problems, the drag button is the dificult one for me.

right now the app has an invisible wpf button placed on top of the html one, the window can drag and the wpf button is not visible yet clickeable, but i was wondering if there is a better way to drag the host window of the awesomium webcontrol from the webpage.